# positioning an image below a color bar using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to position the blue image below the gold color bar in flutter. The link to the image is below.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVRff.png)

```
 return Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
        end: Alignment.centerRight,
        colors: [Color.fromRGBO(242,88,88,1.0),Color.fromRGBO(200, 88, 88, 1.0)]
      ),
    ),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Color(0xFFEE970B),
          height: 125,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        ),
      ]
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Stack Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) to stack widgets on top of each other.
If that's not what you wanted, please specify your question.

Comment: No not one on top of the other. Just one below the other one. color bar then the blue image below.

Comment: Then simply put a second Widget in the children List. Something like:
`
 child: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Color(0xFFEE970B),
          height: 125,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        ),
        Container(
          color: Color(0x97A8FF0B),
          height: 125,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        ),
      ]
    ),
`

Comment: When I add another container it is leaving a space between the gold bar and the image. I do not want any space. To solve this I added the image below the gold color bar container without a widget. It worked for now. I have text to add on the image.Image.asset('data',
        height: 300,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
        ),